# iOS8 performSegueWithIdentifier run too slow

Tags: iphone, performance, ios8, segue, uistoryboardsegue

This only happens in iOS8.

if I run "performSegueWithIdentifier" inside a button click handler. eg.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueFromMenuToList" sender:self];
}
```

Then it works fine.

But if I show a alertview. And then in the alerview delegate handler, call "performSegueWithIdentifier", it would take 4 seconds to load!

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueFromMenuToList" sender:self];
}
```

This only happen the first time I call "performSegueWithIdentifier" and only happens under iOS 8.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**

Tried to run in UI thread doesn't solve the problem.

1. If it only lags the first time, is there any way to preload it?
2. Why this only happens for iOS 8?

Answer (score -2):

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS8. Start using UIAlertController.
Its running slow in iOS8 because it has to perform 2 tasks. One is to remove the alert view and the other is to display the segue. There's possibility to crash at times (which I faced)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried UIAlertController, but it still lags about 3-4 secs. It's odd that this only happens in iOS 8, while in iOS7, it loads almost instantly.